# How to change the go botton into a Loop botton on netlogo

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

Change the ‘go’ button from looping infinitely (‘forever’) to running for 1000 ticks.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

One way, based on pure ticks:

```
to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
end

to go 
  if ticks = 1000 [ stop ]
  ; Actions here
  tick
end
```